# Randomly assign Products to Transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Table: Transaction

```
ID Date  
1  11-01 
2  11-01 
3  11-02 
4  11-10 
5  11-12
```

Table: Product

```
ID  Name 
100 ABC  
101 CDE  
102 DEF
```

Result

```
ID Date  Product
1  11-01 100
2  11-01 101
3  11-02 102
4  11-10 101
5  11-12 102
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an inline query:

```
select 
    t.id,
    t.date,
    (select top 1 id from product order by newid()) product
from transaction t
```

The inline subquery with `top 1` and `order by newid()` gives you a random record in the `product` table.

---

**Edit**

It seems like the above query does not generate enough entropy. Probably, SQLServer optimizes the query and only runs the inline query once.

The following seems to work:

```
select id, date, product
from (
    select 
        t.id,
        t.date,
        p.id product,
        row_number() over(partition by t.id, t.date order by newid()) rn
    from Transaction t
    cross join Product p
) t
where rn = 1
```

This works by generating a cartesian product between the tables, assigning a random rank to each product for each given `(id, date)`, and then filtering on the top record per group.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ebdf5dd2a2a46083845873f7513ff56b)**:

```
id | date  | product
-: | :---- | ------:
 1 | 11-01 |     100
 2 | 11-01 |     101
 3 | 11-02 |     100
 4 | 11-10 |     102
 5 | 11-12 |     101
```

NB: `transaction` is a reserved work in SQL; don't use that for a table name in real life...

Comment: When I run, the same productid is repeated for all the transactions, though the productid is picked up different in different executions

Comment: @Senthil_Arun: yes I discovered that while testing... I updated my answer with a new solution, that seems to work.

Comment: I have millions of transactions and around 1000 products, what will be the performance impact, anyways am checking on my side

Comment: Welcome @Senthil_Arun! Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I find that a correlated subquery works fine:

```
select t.id, t.date,
       (select top 1 id
        from product p
        where t.id <> p.id
        order by newid()
       ) product
from transaction t;
```